# Switching themes in a Polymer shadow DOM element

Tags: polymer

We're making a fairly complex app that will have different sets of CSS files to apply to various custom elements. What is a good way to dynamically switch an included stylesheet?

from

```
<template>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../themes/dark.css">
  <div id="container"></div>
</template>
```

to

```
<template>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../themes/light.css">
  <div id="container"></div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Platform support for style sheets inside of shadow-roots barely exists, so Polymer does lots of tricks to try to make it look easy. To maintain sane performance, Polymer does these things as a preprocess when setting up an element type.

The upshot is that it's hard to load or manipulate a stylesheet inside a shadow-root at runtime like this.

One thing you can do today is use the `/shadow/` and `/shadow-deep/` combinators (formerly ^ and ^^) to construct a stylesheet that lives in the main document but can still style element innards. This way you can use standard techniques to control your stylesheet dynamics.

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/shadow-styling/#inheritance

Also note that you should put the attribute `shim-shadowdom` on any style or link tag not in an Polymer template that uses the new combinators, if you want them to be polyfilled on non-supporting browsers.

e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="sheet.css" shim-shadowdom>`

See http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html#sdcss

Comment: I couldn't get cats and hats to work with both native and polyfill. Tricks there?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific, maybe provide a JSBin?

Comment: With `/shadow/` a stylesheet that lives in the main document, it works in Chrome Canary, but not Chrome 33 or Firefox. Without, it is reversed.

Comment: `/shadow/` is brand new, literally in the past couple of days. Make sure you update Polymer to the latest version.

Comment: [This example from the docs](http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html#style-distributed) works in Chrome 35 but not Chrome 33 or Firefox: http://i.imgur.com/XTqIRKt.png

Comment: OK, `html /shadow-deep/ button` in page style works with native but not polyfill. `button-thing /shadow/ button` in the custom element style works with both. http://jsbin.com/zabid/3/edit

Comment: Oh, missed the `shim-shadowdom` tip. Now it works from outside.

Comment: Is it always up to date since the new version of polymer ?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way that comes to my mind is:

```
<template id="myTempl" bind>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../themes/{{theme}}.css">
  <div id="container">Hello {{theme}}</div>
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("myTempl").model={
        theme: "dark" //"light"
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry @tomalec, this won't work today. `<link rel="stylesheet">` is not supported by ShadowDOM spec, so this is a place where Polymer is trying to point the way for the browser vendors via JavaScript. The way we do that is with tricks that are not easy to generalize (e.g. work dynamically) without destroying performance.

Comment: Sorry for the noise, as you posted it, it's just a template, so that can work. It won't work inside of a Polymer element, which was the usage implied in the OP.